# Best way to make thousands of get requests in python

Tags: python, networking, concurrency, queue

Right now I am working on a python script which takes in a list of url's as an argument, then performs a GET request on each url and then searches through the output with xpath to fingerprint the website. It seems to work like a charm when the list is around 50 sites long, but anything after that causes the program to slow down to the point where it stop (usually around 150 sites). Scroll down to where you see main app logic and the relevant code it below. Right now I am just using 50 elements in the array and it works fine, but anything after makes the entire program stop. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Web Scraper
# 1.0

# Imports for file
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
from lxml import html
import requests
import time
import sys

# Get Raw HTML
def scrape(url):
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, timeout=2.0)
        if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            html_page = html.fromstring(page.content)
            s =requests.session()
            s.close()
            return html_page
        else:
            s =requests.session()
            s.close()
            return False
    except:
        s =requests.session()
        s.close()
        return False


# Format URL
def format_url(url):
    if url.find("http://") == -1:
        url = "http://"+url
    if url[-1] == "/":
        url = url[:-1]
    return url


# Check if WordPress Site
def check_wordpress(tree):
    scripts = tree.xpath("//script[contains(@src,'wp-content')]")
    if len(scripts) > 0:
        return True
    return False



# Check WordPress Version
def wordpress_version(tree):
    type = tree.xpath("//meta[@name='generator']/@content")
    version = 0
    if len(type) > 0:
        details = type[0].split()
        if len(details)>1 and details[0] == "WordPress":
            if len(details) > 1:
                version = details[1]
            else:
                version = type[0]
    return version

# Find Contact Page
def find_contact_page(tree):
    contact = tree.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact')]/@href")
    try_xpath = 1
    while len(contact) == 0:
        if try_xpath == 1:
            contact = tree.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Contact')]/../@href")
        elif try_xpath == 2:
            contact = tree.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Contact')]/../@href")
        elif try_xpath == 3:
            break
        try_xpath+=1
    if len(contact) > 0:
        contact = contact[0]
        if contact.find('#') == -1:
            if contact[0] == '/':
                contact = url + "" + contact
        print contact   


# Juicer method
def juice(url):
    url = format_url(url)
    string = url
    tree = scrape(url)
    if tree == False:
        return string + " \t\t\t No XML tree"
    elif check_wordpress(tree) == True:
        version = wordpress_version(tree)
        return string + " \t\t\t WordPress: " + str(version)
    else:
        return string + " \t\t\t Not WordPress"


# Main App Logic Below ------------------------------------->


# Open list of websites from given argument
list = open(sys.argv[1],'r').read().split('\n')

# Juice url
def juice_url():
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        result = juice(url)
        print result
        q.task_done()

# Create concurrent queues
concurrent = 50
q = Queue(concurrent)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=juice_url)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()


# Add URL to Queue
time1 = time.time()
for url in list[0:50]:
    q.put(url)
q.join()

# Calculate total time
total = time.time() - time1
print "Total Time: %f" % total
print "Average Time: %f" % (total/50)
```

Comment: Surely this is *inevitably* a slow process? Even if you do a lot of parallelisation, the network is generally the slowest thing you talk to. Have you looked into existing tools for this, like scrapy?

Comment: Haven't looked into scrapy yet, was hoping to build from scratch. What baffles me is that it works really fast for 50 websites, so then I tried only doing chunks of 50 at a time but around 150 it just plain stops which baffles me. I'm wondering if I need to close the connections, or clear the queue, both of which I have tried to no avail...

Comment: Your problem is that you think you need as many threads as URLs. That's false; your processor can only handle a certain number of threads at a time, the rest is just overhead. You need a smaller number of threads that each take an item out of the queue until it is empty.

Comment: I have honestly tried from 2 threads to about 100 threads, and 50 seemed to be the sweet spot. But I just changed it and it still has trouble after doing the first 50 websites.